# Kill the applications running in background in android

Tags: android, background, kill-process

I am trying to kill the background running applications using my application, but i unable to kill the process.

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
android.os.Process.sendSignal(pid,
android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
manager.killBackgroundProcesses(pid);
```

here pid is background running process id.

Comment: Why?  You should not be killing background processes.

Comment: Which process is takes high memory and battery usage also, i want to close that type of application process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every Android app has its own user id, group id, and most of the time runs within its own process. So your app probably have no privilege to kill other process.

There is obviously a design flaw, you'd be better state out what actually you want to do.

Comment: I want to close the applications which are previously open and run in background, using my application.

Comment: Reasonable case would be that you *TELL* the applications to "close", otherwise I think your application is not allowed to forcibly close another application.

Of course there must be a mechanism present in the to-be-closed applications to "accept" such requests, that probably means you are also the author of those applications.

Answer (score 1):

Use this killBackgroundProcesses:

```
   try {
            ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            actvityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(pkgn.toString());// pkgn is a process id /////
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have to add this in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```